# Cannot track mouse moves correctly, setMouseTracking has no effect - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I am working on a project that has been started by someone else, so I cannot change the structure of the code.
The code of my class is the following (this is just a sample):

```
class myClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myClass();
    ~myClass();
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *e);

private:
    QMainWindow* window;
    FRAMEWORK_InfoWidget *zone_notif;
};
```

So, my class contains a QmainWindow "window", and a custom widget "zone_notif" (basically a rectangle). I want to display a message when the mouse cursor passes over "zone_notif", and another message when it comes out.
I first tried the following :

```
myClass::myClass():QWidget()
{
    window = new QMainWindow();
    window->setFixedSize(SCREEN_REZOLUTION);
    window->setWindowTitle(QString("window"));

    zone_notif = new FRAMEWORK_InfoWidget(restit_window);
    zone_notif->setGeometry(299, 452, 320, 55);

    window->installEventFilter(this);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    delete zone_notif;
    delete window;
}

bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        int x = cursor().pos().x() - restit_window->geometry().x();
        int y = cursor().pos().y() - restit_window->geometry().y();
        qDebug() << "Moving !";
        if((x > zone_notif->pos().x()) && (x < zone_notif->pos().x() + zone_notif->width()) && (y > zone_notif->pos().y()) && (y < zone_notif->pos().y() + zone_notif->height()))
        {
            qDebug() << "OVER !";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "IN !";
        }
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, e);
}
```

But it only works if I press the mouse button before moving.

I found a dirty solution :

```
bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::Enter)
    {
        qDebug() << "ENTREE";
        window->grabMouse();
        return true;
    }
    else if(e->type() == QEvent::Leave)
    {
        qDebug() << "Sortie";
        window->releaseMouse();
        return true;
    }
    else if(e->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        int x = cursor().pos().x() - restit_window->geometry().x();
        int y = cursor().pos().y() - restit_window->geometry().y();
        qDebug() << "Moving !";
        if((x > zone_notif->pos().x()) && (x < zone_notif->pos().x() + zone_notif->width()) && (y > zone_notif->pos().y()) && (y < zone_notif->pos().y() + zone_notif->height()))
        {
            qDebug() << "OVER !";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "IN !";
        }
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, e);
}
```

But this solution isn't correct. My application contains other windows, and if I set my QMainWindow fullscreen, I never get out of it so my other windows are not clickable anymore.

I tried to change `window->setMouseTracking(true)` to `zone_notif->setMouseTracking(true)` and the same with ìnstallEventFilter` but it has no effect.

I also tried to override mouseMoveEvent :

```
void myClass::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << "I am here !";
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(e);
}
```

But it never gets called.

Do you have an idea how I could make it work ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution.

To be sure to catch the mouse move event, I have installed an event Filter on my QApplication.

I created a new class "myEventFilter", and this class gets installed as the event Filter.

myEventFilter.h

```
#ifndef MYEVENTFILTER_H
#define MYEVENTFILTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class myEventFilter: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
  myEventFilter();
  ~myEventFilter();

protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject* object,QEvent* event);
};

#endif // MYEVENTFILTER_H
```

myEventFilter.cpp

```
#include "myEventFilter.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCursor>

myEventFilter::myEventFilter():QObject()
{}

myEventFilter::~myEventFilter()
{}

bool myEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        int x = QCursor::pos().x();
        int y = QCursor::pos().y();
        qDebug() << "I am here -> (" + QString::number(x) + "," + QString::number(y) + ")";
        return true;
    }
    else
        return object->eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "myEventFilter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow sw = new QMainWindow();
    sw->show();
    a.installEventFilter(new myEventFilter());

    return a.exec();
}
```

And it works !

Comment: Your `eventFilter` is criminally wrong: The system passes the events to all installed event filters automatically, if you return `false`. Calling an arbitrary event filter, and returning its return value is going to cause havoc at some point. There's also no need to explicitly call the event filter's base class' c'tor. Plus, you're installing it too late.

Answer (score 1):

Override QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)

You should get the event when mouse tracking is on.

Comment: I tried to override mouseMoveEvent as you adviced but it never gets called, wether I press the mouse button or not.
I have edited my question to add the code

Comment: Thats because you filter the event and return true for handled. Remove the event filter and just override mouseMoveEvent. It must work.

Comment: even after removing everything about eventFilters (including the code that I posted as an answer), the overridden method `myClass::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *)` never gets called

Comment: The zone_notif widget is where you want to track mouse movement and override the mouseMoveEvent

Comment: Unfortunately, this widget comes from a FRAMEWORK, I only have access to the header "FRAMEWORK_InfoWidget.h", I don't have access to the class definition. So I won't be able to override mouseMoveEvent for this widget.

Fortunately I have found a way to catch mouse events by installing an event filter on my QApplication.

Comment: Should also work if you install the event filter on the zen_motif widget?

Comment: You mean by changing `window->installEventFilter(this)`to `zone_notif->installEventFilter(this)` in myClass constructor ?
I already tried this, and it has no effect.

Comment: Hmm... Then for getting the mouseMoveEvent working you could also intercept the event for the framework widget in 
bool QApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent * event)

Comment: Oops sorry posted too early. and return false, it should then propagate the event to its parent widget. Whichever way is cleaner for you.